# Sharing Cases owned by "High Volume Customer Portal User" with Account Owner?

Tags: sharing, roles, sharing-sets, high-volume-portal

I've have the following (simplified) scenario:

Role Hierarchy:

```
Company -> EMEA -> Account Manager (EMEA)
        -> US -> Account Manager (US)
```

The "Account Manager" roles (both) are configured like this:

> Case Access: Users in this role can **edit** all cases associated with
> accounts that they own, regardless of who owns the cases

OWD for Cases are: Private

*Emma* is an "EMEA Account Manager" (internal user) and owns Account "ACME".

ACME has a Contact and High Volume Customer Portal User (HV User) named "Henry".
Henry created and owns a Case (Case no. 4711) that is linked to ACME and Henry's contact.

There is another internal user "*Uma*", who is in the "US Account Manager" role.
She also owns a case for ACME (Case no. 1234).

My question now: Why does Emma only see case no. 1234 (the one owned by the US Account Manager Uma)?

According to my configuration she should be able to see both cases related to ACME (because of the role configuration - it says "regardless of who owns the cases").

When I share the cases via sharing group it works but that's not really what I want.

This shows who can currently see what (without sharing groups):

| Case | Emma (Account Owner) | Uma (other role branch) | Henry (HV User) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4711 (owned by HV User) | **No (WHY?)** | No | Yes |
| 1234 (owned by internal User) | Yes | Yes | No |

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5), HV Portal users cannot be assigned to roles, so role-based sharing doesn't apply to them.  You have to use sharing groups.

Comment: Thanks David, but I'm aware of that documentation. The HV user owns the case but Emma owns the account. I'm not expecting the case to be shared through the role hierarchy (which btw is also not the case for Uma's case). So according to the role configuration for the internal user (Emma) it should not matter who owns any of the account's cases. Emma should see all...